# A question on the proof of pullback bundles by homotopic maps are isomorphic in Prof. Ralph Cohen notes

Tags: homotopy-theory, vector-bundles

Here is a question about proving the pullback bundles by homotopic maps are isomorphic in Prof. Ralph Cohen notes [Bundles, Homotopy, and Manifolds](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Eralph/book.pdf). The proof is in page 73 of the notes. For me, considering only vector bundles is good enough.

The statement is: let $E\to B$ be a vector bundle and $f_0, f_1:X\to B$ are two homotopic maps. Then $f_0^*E\cong f_1^*E$. The proof is attached.

In the proof, the homotopy $\tilde{H}:f_0^*E\times I\to E$, which covers $H:X\times I\to B$, is at the same time a bundle isomorphism. And we get a bundle isomorphism $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$ by restricting $\tilde{H}$ to $X\times\{1\}$.

My question is: if we restrict $\tilde{H}$ to $X\times\{0\}$, we get a bundle isomorphism $f_0^*E\to f_0^*E$, probably the identity map. Does it mean the bundle isomorphism $\tilde{H}:f_0^*E\times I\to E$ is a homotopy between the bundle isomorphism $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$ and the bundle isomorphism $f_0^*E\to f_0^*E$? It looks like the answer is yes, but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: $f_0^*E$ and $f_1^*E$ are two different bundles, for which the theorem gives an isomorphism $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$. So it's not clear what you mean by a homotopy from the identity on $f_0^*E$ to that isomorphism. What is true is that the isomorphism is determined only up to homotopy (between isomorphisms $f_0^*E \to f_1^*E$).

Comment: @SteveCostenoble Sorry, that's a typo. But when you say the isomorphism $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$ is determined only up to homotopy, do you mean any two isomorphisms $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$ are homotopic, and moreover, the homotopy is an isomorphism $f_0^*E\times I\to f_1^*E$?

Comment: No, not that any two isomorphisms whatsoever are homotopic. However, $\tilde H$ is only determined up to homotopy (over $H$) and you could vary the homotopy $H$ up to homotopy rel endpoints. The resulting isomorphisms $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$ will all be homotopic. On the other hand, if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two homotopies not homotopic rel endpoints, you could end up with two non-homotopic isomorphisms.

Comment: And, again, it doesn't make sense to ask that a map $f_0^*E\to f_0^*E$ be homotopic to a map $f_0^*E\to f_1^*E$, since the targets are different bundles.

Comment: Another note, sorry: Where you refer to "the bundle isomorphism $\tilde H\colon f_0^*E\times I \to E$," what you really have is an isomorphism $\tilde H\colon f_0^*E\times I\to H^*E$ of bundles over $X\times I$, as in the proof you attached.

Comment: @SteveCostenoble Thank you for the detailed explanation. In the case I am considering, the maps $f_0$ and $f_1$, and the homotopy $H$ can be written down explicitly. Now I understand that the homotopy $\tilde{H}:f_0^*E\times I\to H^*E$ is only determined up to homotopy (over $H$), as you said. Indeed, your comments kind of solve one of the questions in my mind.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the example of the Klein bottle. It is obtained by gluing the top and the bottom of a cylinder along an orientation reversing diffeomorphism. The map that sends a point to its "height" is a bundle over $S^1$.